# Chaining the map function to the Array Constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, inline

Trying to find a way to inline the creation of an array of data given its size, i tried

```
var n = 4;
var data = (new Array(n)).map(function(x) { return 1 });
```

which gave me

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Regarding that

```
new Array(n)
```

gives

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

and that

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined].map(function(x) { return 1 });
```

returns

```
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

I would expect to be able to chain the Array constructor and the map function.

Any insights on that behavior ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new Array(n)` creates an array of size `n`, but with no elements in it. This is called a sparse array. Though there are no elements in the array, the browser represents them as `undefined`. And `Array.prototype.map` will ignore the array elements which are not defined yet.

Quoting from the [ECMA 5.1 Specification for `Array.prototype.map`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19),

> *callbackfn* is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

To be able to chain the `map` function, you might want to do like this

```
console.log(Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(function(x) { return 1 }));
# [ 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
```

Comment: Thanks! I also noticed that the browser representation is actually different (Chrome) : new Array(2) returns [undefined x2] not [undefined, undefined]